# Derivation of moment generating function of a mixture of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

**Question**

Let $Z$, $X$ and $Y$ be random variables, where $Z$ is formed by choosing a sample from $X$ with probability $q$ or a sample from $Y$ with probability $1 - q$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have moment generating functions $M_X(t)$ and $M_Y(t)$ respectively, then show that the moment generating function of $Z$ is $$M_Z(t) = qM_X(t) + (1 - q)M_Y(t).$$

**My working**

$$\begin{aligned}
M_Z(t) & = \mathbb{E}\left(e^{tZ}\right)\\[2 mm]
& = \mathbb{E}\left\{e^{t[qX + (1 - q)Y]}\right\}\\[2 mm]
& = \mathbb{E}\left(e^{tqX}\right)\mathbb{E}\left(e^{t(1 - q)Y}\right)\\[2 mm]
& = M_X(tq)M_Y[t(1 - q)]
\end{aligned}$$
Here, I am stuck. If my working is correct so far, then how should I proceed to show the desired expression for $M_Z(t)$?

---

Any intuitive explanations or suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: $e^{a+b}$ is not $e^{a}+e^{b}$.

Comment: The result is false without independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for the pointers. Please see my updated post!

Comment: $Z=qX+(1-q)Y$ is not correct. Do you know what it means to choosing a sample from $X$ with probability $q$ or a sample from $Y$ with probability $1 - q$?

Comment: @geetha290krm Why? Or rather, what should be the relationship between $Z$, $X$ and $Y$ then?

Comment: $e^{tZ}= e^{tX}$ with probability $q$ and $= e^{tY}$ with probability $1-q$.  This makes find its expectation easy

Comment: @Henry Shouldn't it be $Z$ = $X$ with probability $q$ such that $e^{tZ} = e^{tqX}$ and analogous for the relationship between $Z$ and $Y$?

Comment: @EthanMark Whenever $Z=X$ you have $e^{tZ}=e^{tX}$, not $=e^{tqX}$

Comment: @Henry Oh, that makes sense but requires some deep level of thought, at least from me.  Thank you! Would you consider writing this as an answer, so that I may accept it and close the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Requested from comments:*

- If we were looking for $\mathbb E\left[Z \right]$ with independence of $X$ and $Y$  from which is chosen, we would say $\mathbb E\left[Z\right] = q\mathbb E\left[X\right] + (1-q)\mathbb E\left[Y\right]$
- Whenever $Z=X$ you have $e^{tZ}=e^{tX}$. Similarly with $Z=Y$
- So with probability $q$ we set $e^{tZ}=e^{tX}$ and  $=e^{tY}$ with probability $1−q$.
- With independence of $X$ and $Y$ from which is chosen, this give the desired  expectation $\mathbb E\left[e^{tZ}\right] = q\mathbb E\left[e^{tX}\right] + (1-q)\mathbb E\left[e^{tY}\right]$